# Prove that $0.\overline{123} = 0.123123123123...$ is rational

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

How are we to go about proving that $0.\overline{123} =  0.123123123123...$ can be expressed in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e is rational?

Is this to be done using arithmetic or geometric progressions?

Comment: Geometric. But surely this question, or equivalent, has been asked & answered here many times. Please search for earlier occurrences.

Comment: Well, with the primary school algorithm you could compute directly $p$ and $q$, and then prove that $p/q=0.\overline{123}$ with the division, but I'm guessing the purpose was to have you write down what $0.\overline{123}$ is and then use some property of series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this has been asked before, but directly answering your question :

$$0.\overline{123} =  0.123123123123... = 0.123 + 0.000123 + 0.000000123 + \ldots$$
$$= 123\times10^{-3} + 123\times10^{-6} + 123\times10^{-9} + \ldots $$
$$ = 123 \cdot (10^{-3} + 10^{-6} + 10^{-9} + \ldots)$$
$$ = 123\cdot \left( \frac{10^{-3}}{1-10^{-3}} \right) $$
$$ = \frac{41}{333}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: notice that if $a = 0.\overline{123}$. Then $1000a = 123 + a$

Comment: @lulu you're right.